# How to update react component state from one component to another, and call any functions from any component

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

I am very new to react, when I put everything in one place, it works fine. But when I split it into components, everything went wrong.

I have two files App.js and Activity1.js

Activity1.js contains an input with an event handler attached to it. This input is simply wrapped inside a div.

The input was initially in App.js but I extracted it to Activity.js.

The input has a sibling, a div where I echo whatever the user types in the input, by updating the props state. How can I update the state. Your time and interest is appreciated.

Here's my code:

App.js

```js
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import Activity1 from './f/Activity1';
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value:15};
  }
  checkInput = e => {
    this.setState({value: e.target.value});
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="p-2">
        <div>
          <Activity1 />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }


}
export default App;
```

Here's Activity1.js

```js
import React from "react";
class Activity1 extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Enter Number</div>
        <input className="form-control" onChange={this.checkInput} />
        <div className="p-2 mt-3">{this.state.value}</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Activity1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function as a prop to the other component.

```
<div>
      <Activity1 checkInput={this.checkInput} inputValue = {this.state.value}/>
</div>
```

In your Activity1 component,

```
const {checkInput, inputValue} = this.props;
onChangeEventHandler= () => {
    checkInput();
}
```

and

```
<input className = "form-control" onChange = ={this.onChangeEventHandler} />
<div className = "p-2 mt-3"> {this.inputValue} </div>
```

https://dev.to/vadims4/passing-down-functions-in-react-4618

Comment: This makes sense to me, however, it still did not solve the problem. It seems that the DOM or Virtual DOM or whatever does not know where to find the value. I would love an active react developer to actually attempt the code or scenario. I actually appreciate your input.

Comment: @smacaz, , I have updated my answer with the code which you can use in your Activity1 compo. Hope this will help to you. I am not in a position to write the exact code right now. anyway this is just a normal scenario in React.js. So hope this code will help you. also you can refer the above link as well.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this solves the problem.

app.js

```
...
<Activity1 checkInput = {this.checkInput} inputValue = {this.state.value}/>
...
```

Activity1.js

```
...
render() {
    const {checkInput, inputValue} = this.props;
    ...
    <input className = "form-control" onChange = {checkInput} />
    <div className = "p-2 mt-3"> {inputValue} </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Callback function

```
<Activity checkInput = {this.checkInput} inputValue = {this.checkInput.bind(this)}/>
```